# How to receive the result after sending data via WebSocket

Tags: node.js, websocket

Using `ws` package from npm you can do something like that:

```js
const ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:9003');
ws.on('open', () => ws.send('rcon_password PASSWORD'));
ws.on('message', result => console.log(result));
```

If server expects client to send password then returns authentication result, how can i check result sent by server?
In Python you could do something like:

```py
async with websockets.connect('ws://localhost:9003') as websocket:
  await websocket.send('rcon_password PASSWORD')
  result = await websocket.recv()
```

Client can send other commands later. How to relate data sent with `ws.send()` with those sent to another function in the event `onmessage`?

Answer (score 4):

The webSocket protocol itself has no concept of a response to a message you send.  And, because Javascript is event driven, you can't just block waiting for the response).  So, the server just needs to send a message back to the client and the client needs to have a handler for incoming messages and handle the response appropriately when it arrives.  If you need to make sure it's a response to THE specific message you previously sent to the server, then you can include some sort of messageID (that you coin yourself) when you send the first message and include that same messageID in the server response.

If you step up to the socket.io library for both client and server (which runs on top of the webSocket transport), then it has built-into it the concept of a response to your message.  When sending your message, you just register a callback that gets called when the response comes back and the server has to handle its side appropriately to trigger the response callback on the client.